# XCode - How to create bundled CLI tool application

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-system-extension

I'm new to XCode, so maybe I'm missing something that is very easy, but how can I create a CLI tool with XCode and bundle it with a system extension I compiled?

I want to create a console app that is bundled with my system extension and install/uninstall it.
As I understand, the extension should reside in the Contents/Library/SystemExtensions of the application([info from here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemextensions/installing_system_extensions_and_drivers?language=objc)).

From what I've found, I succeeded only to make a GUI/UI app but not a CLI app that can bundle things inside it.